# Test database availability on server startup

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, startup

I'm developing a Spring webapp that uses Hibernate. Currently, if my MySQL database is not available (for example simply not launched), the server starts up normally, and an exception get thrown the first time an Hibernate query gets triggered.

Is there any way to rather check the database availability at server startup?

Here is my current applicationContext:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.user}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}"
    p:maxActive="${dbcp.maxActive}"
    p:maxIdle="${dbcp.maxIdle}"
    p:maxWait="${dbcp.maxWait}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:packagesToScan="com.myapp.data.domain">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: I think it is not possible direct way, though you can check indirect way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple bean that validates the `dataSource` in a method that is invoked after all properties are set. This is possible with the `@PostConstruct` annotation or by implementing `InitializingBean`. With annotations this might look like this:

```
@Compontent
public class DataSourceValdationBean {

  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowire
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void validateDataSource() {
    try {
       Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();
       Statement s = c.createStatement();
       s.excuteQuery("SELECT 1");  // you have to change this depending on your DBMS
    } catch (SQLException | SQLTimeoutException e) {
       // log error and throw exception
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easier way, but you could create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and run a test query from `contextInitialized()`. If there is any uncatched exception, the servlet container will fail to start.

Comment: I think he was saying the same thing in the question and asks for the answer.